# How to format a time given in HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

From the server I get the time as String HH:MM:SS. I only want to show HH:MM. What is the right way to achieve that?

```
"12:30:00" convert to "12:30"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this

without momentjs. using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and  [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const time ="12:30:00"
console.log(time.split(':').slice(0,2).join(':'))
```

Or with Momentjs

```js
const time ="12:30:00"
console.log(moment(time,"HH:mm:ss").format('HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged `momentjs`, Here I am using `momentJs`

```
const time = "12:30:00";
const formattedTime = moment(time,"HH:mm:ss").format('HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` or `substr` method of string to get only the HH:MM time

```
const time ="12:30:00";

console.log(time.slice(0, 5)) // 12:30

console.log(time.substr(0, 5)) // 12:30
```